# Proving that $0$ is a limit point of the reciprocals of the positive integers

Tags: real-analysis

How should I start a proof of the following?

> If $M$ is set of all reciprocals of positive integers then $0$ is a limit point of $M.$

It makes sense to me when I think this problem visually, on a number line, but I'm lacking back try to write my thoughts down from top to bottom as a proof !

Comment: What is your definition of limit point?

Comment: M is a point set and P is element of all real numbers. Then p is a limit point of M if for every open interval containing p also contains a point of M different from p.

Comment: OK, good!  So consider an (arbitrary) open interval containing zero.  How can you show it contains an element of $M$?

Comment: Let me  choose (a,b) in which zero is element of of (a,b) then i  can not proceed for this interval contains element of M

Comment: But isn't that exactly what you want?

Comment: ???? What do you mean?

Comment: M is a point set and p is element of all real numbers. Then p is a limit point of M if for every open interval containing p also contains a point of M different from p.

Comment: This is what I would like to prove then how am I going to proceed after I hvae chosen my arbitrary interval?

Comment: You said, paraphrasing, let an interval $(a,b)$ be given that contains $0$.  Now quoting, “Then I cannot proceed for [by which I read, *because*] this interval contains an element of $M$.”  But to satisfy the definition that's exactly what we want—an element of $M$, as long as it's not $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume the contrary then you would be able to find a set of open balls that is centered at 0 but contain no other elements in M.Let S be the ball with the largest radius.It is simple to see that an element of M must lie on the boundary of the ball since otherwise,there exist another ball with larger radius.Hence,the next element in M must lie inside S for its distance to the previous point is larger than 0

Comment: I'm not sure this works.  Your “set” of open balls containing $0$ but not other elements of $M$ could be finite.  This wouldn't have the maximality property you want to use.  Maybe if you start with the union of all open intervals containing $0$ but no other point of $M$...but then you run into the unboundedness on the left.

Comment: I don't understand what maximality property so I can't make sense of your argument.Can you rephrase it?

Comment: You say “Let $S$ be the ball with the largest radius...an element of $M$ must lie on the boundary of $S$ since otherwise, there exists another ball with larger radius.”  If the given set of open balls were finite, it's not necessarily true that there always exists a ball of larger radius.

Comment: It is required that the condition for there to be another ball of larger radius is that an element of M does not lie on the boundary

Comment: OK, I think I understand your argument.  So when you say “find a set of open balls that contain zero but no other point of $M$,” you mean to take the collection of *all* such balls, right?

Comment: Guys, I'll try to understand and convert your conversations to aid me with the proof but it is not helping me:-( Can we put in a more formal form?

Comment: @Matthew:No but it's fine that way I think. On rethinking it, I should have put S to be the set of balls centered at 0,or the union of such balls      .   For Masli:I will edit the proof to be clearer when we finish discussing it so stay tuned

Comment: @billy9797: In that case I still don't understand your proof.  You need to be more precise about whether the set of open balls is being *described by you* or *supplied to you* as evidence that $0$ is not a limit point.

Comment: I edit my comment above and my answer.I hope it makes more sense this time.I describe a set of such balls then state that assuming the contrary to what to be proven, the ball of the largest radius must have an element of M on its boundary,else it cannot be the ball with largest radius

Comment: @Matthew:I read your answer which is much simpler and easier to understand than my mine,so I would say it's the best for the OP. Can we still discuss my proof?

Comment: I think the best way to frame your argument is: let $S$ be the set of all $\epsilon$ such that $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ contains no element of $M$.  If $S$ is nonempty [it is already bounded above, perhaps by $1$], it must have a least upper bound; call it $b$.  Then you can show $b$ must be in $M$, otherwise there is an $\epsilon$ larger than $b$ in $S$.  It follows that the “next” element of $M$ (that is, largest element of $M$ smaller than $b$) is in $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$, and in fact in an smaller interval.  This contradicts the definition of $b$.

Comment: That's sounded great.Do you mind if I replace it into my answer?

Answer (score 0):

We want to show that every open interval containing $0$ also contains a point of $M$ (we could say “different from $0$”, but since $0\notin M$, that's not necessary).

Suppose we are given an open interval $(a,b)$ containing $0$.  In particular $b > 0$.  An element of $m$ that is also in $(a,b)$ would require a positive integer $n$ such that $\frac{1}{n} < b$.  Does such an integer exist?  How do you know?

Comment: Every 1/n would be less than b. Except n=1